# how to ignore self signed certificate error node.js soap.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, soap-client

I have created a soap client in node.js using [soap.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/soap).Soap communication is done over https. When I try to connect I keep getting this error

> { [Error: self signed certificate] code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
>   }

Below is my code

```
var url = '../public/test.wsdl';

var client = soap.createClient(url,sslOptions, function(err, client) {
    client.setSecurity(new soap.WSSecurity('testuser', 'testpassword'));
      client.CheckStatus(args, function(err, result) {
          console.log(err);
        //  console.log(result);
      });

  });
```

I've also tried the following ssl setting but did't work out

```
sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync( '../certs/test-key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync( '../certs/test-cert.pem'),
  rejectUnauthorized : false,
  secureOptions : constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2,
  strictSSL : false
};
```

Any help would be appreciated  !!

Comment: Googled "how to ignore self signed certificate error node.js soap.js". First result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Found it yesterday on their github [repo](https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap/issues/459)

> @tesfel tesfel commented on 17 Feb
>
> Add the cert to your trusted list at you computer or add
>
> ```
> process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0"
> ```
>
> to your code.

Comment: note - this is super insecure as it disable all SSL checking in Node. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433287/node-js-request-cert-has-expired#answer-29397100 for a more secure way.

Comment: Super-insecure or not, this helped me to quickly get over an early development hurdle, thank you. I will be using genuine certificates in production.

Comment: I wish there was a place where all these weird env vars are documented. E.g. this one does not appear in https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html.

Makes me wonder if there is another var that allows you to specify just your own certificate as trusted.