# How to ignore invalid ssl cert using javascript request library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, npm, request

Is there a way to ignore invalid ssl certs using the popular request library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

I'm using this in a nodejs server to make an https request to a server with a self-signed cert and need to be able to ignore the invalid ssl cert.

I couldn't find an option for this in the documentation, does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add: `agentOptions.ca = [ selfSignedRootCaPemCrtBuffer ];`

[Node.js request CERT_HAS_EXPIRED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433287/node-js-request-cert-has-expired)