# Is there a way to trust all certificates using socket.io-client in node?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, certificate, client, self-signed

Right now I wanna have a node client, for my socket.io application.
The problem I am having is that I wanna connect to the server using a https connection, but the server is using a self-signed certificate, and I wanna be able to allow all certificates with socket.io-client, otherwise the client rejects the connection.

I am writing a node client, and there are no browsers involved. 
So is there any options to trust all certficates or to allow only some with socket.io-client?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433287/node-js-request-cert-has-expired#answer-29397100