# Issue: Let’s Encrypt Change and your Heroku App

Tags: node.js, heroku, certificate

I have a website built on node 8.9.0 and hosted on Heroku, a recent root certificate used by [Let's Encrypt expired](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/). That's why I am not able to make external API calls.

Is there any way to fix this? I found one [article](https://help.heroku.com/ZBZB0LNB/let-s-encrypt-change-and-your-heroku-app) which says to upgrade node to >9, but due to limitations and dependencies, I am not able to upgrade it. So is there any way to degrade this update just a temporary solution to make the site run, and I can upgrade the website side by side.

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69403683/354577

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to "Configure the server to use the alternative certificate chain which can be requested from Let’s Encrypt with most up-to-date ACME protocol clients"

https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2021/09/13/LetsEncryptRootCertExpire/