# getting CERT_HAS_EXPIRED in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, ssl, request, ca

1. i am using **Node 9.6.1** version, also my SSL is expired after 1 year, but still getting **CERT_HAS_EXPIRED** in response
2. code was same but after some new updates i am getting above error
3. after google i fond that **Lets's encrypt 30th sept. 2021 ROOT CA expiry** word
4. suggest some solution except **process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0** and **const myRequest = require('request').defaults({strictSSL: false})**

   ```
    const request = require('request');
    request.post(reqObj,function (error, response) {
       console.log(response); // getting CERT_HAS_EXPIRED in response
    })
   ```

> help me to solve this issue, without upgrade Node version

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js request CERT\_HAS\_EXPIRED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433287/node-js-request-cert-has-expired)

Comment: @Alghazali505 i have checked that answer, but don't know what to do in my code, my SSL is not expired, can you suggest me what to do??

Comment: can you share more about `reqObj` and `your SSL` and what is the new updates that caused the error ?