# Error occurred while proxying request - CERT_HAS_EXPIRED

Tags: reactjs, server, proxy, localhost, http-proxy-middleware

After spending some considerable amount of time trying to solve this, here I am seeking some help about this issue.

**Problem**

```
[HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/auth/authentication-api/clinic/user/login to https://xyxyx.clinic/ [CERT_HAS_EXPIRED] (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

So I am not able to to make a POST request of the 'login credentials body data; to the `https://xyxyx.clinic/` path and also getting a `500 Internal Server Error` in the browser's network tab inside the dev tools.

**What I have done so far to solve this**

- Checked the validity of the certificate and YES it is valid.
- Upgraded the Nodejs from v8.x.x to V.16.1.4 as per this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69403683/13406292)
- Cleared the node_modules several time, installed dependencies again, even tried restarting and completed my Linux Manjaro updates.
- Rechecked all of my proxy server codes and tested all the backend api endpoints - all were worked well.

[image]

**My findings**

I asked someone else to run this repo in their PC and it was working well - they could log in and out. Am I missing any steps something here ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ANSWER**

Adding "secure:false" solved the issue. So basically secure="false" means requests from both HTTP and HTTPS are allowed.

```
app.use(
'/api',
createProxyMiddleware({
  target: 'https://xyxy.clinic/',
  changeOrigin: true,
  secure: false,
}),
```

)