# Node HTTPS request SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, request

I've been using https://github.com/mikeal/request to make calls to a REST API

When I make a `GET` request over HTTPS with `{ strictSSL: false }` specified in the options. I get the response I'm after and all is fine.

However, If I make a `POST` request also with strictSSL specified I receive an error `SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN`

Here an example of what I've been using:

```
request.post({url: url, headers: headers, strictSSL: false}, function (err, response, body) {


});
```

Does any body know why it works for `GET` requests and no `POST`

Comment: I tried this locally with a https server created using a self-signed certificate (using node's `https` package), and both the GET and POST requests work the same -- both returning the data if I specify the `strictSSL: false` option.  Maybe there's something else going on here?  You might try to isolate this by attempting to build a simple example to test it.

Comment: You should search it first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request

Answer (score 6):

One option that is useful when using self signed certs is to set the following environment variable:

`export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

Comment: In my case also this helped: ```npm config set cafile "<path to your certificate file>"```