# Error: unable to verify the first certificate / How to trust all certificates?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, visual-studio-code

When I try to install an extension I get this error:

```
unable to verify the first certificate
```

I already know that the problem is our internal network structure, which wraps every SSL Certificate with our own and not every application trusts our certificate.

Is it possible to set the property **Trust all SSL certificates** in Visual Studio Code?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore invalid self-signed ssl certificate in node.js with https.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Had the same problem.

Adding environment variable

> NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

fixed it.
Took this answer from here:
[Ignore invalid self-signed ssl certificate in node.js with https.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request/11042814#11042814)

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the SSL problem. Unfortunately i get another error: `end of central directory record signature not found`. I think it's due to our company's proxy server. \*sigh\*

Comment: Need additional help. This generated SSL Error: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Comment: Where do you go to set this setting?

Answer (score 8):

My solution was to add the following to user settings ( File -> Preferences -> User Settings)

```
"http.proxyStrictSSL": false
```