# npm install error - unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, npm-install

I am getting an `unable to get local issuer certificate` error when performing an npm install:

```
typings ERR! message Unable to read typings for "es6-shim". You should check the
 entry paths in "es6-shim.d.ts" are up to date
typings ERR! caused by Unable to connect to "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/D
efinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/7de6c3dd94feaeb21f20054b9f30d5dabc5efabd/es6-shim
/es6-shim.d.ts"
typings ERR! caused by unable to get local issuer certificate
```

I have recently update to node 4 from a much earlier version and it sounds like node is much more strict when these kind of problems arise.

There is an issue discussed [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3742) which talks about using ca files, but it's a bit beyond my understanding and I'm unsure what to do about it.

I am behind a corporate firewall, but I can get to the url fine in a browser without any restriction.

Does anyone have any further insight into this issue and what possible solutions there are?

I'm wondering about reverting to node 0.12 in the meantime :(

Comment: Using the following tool https://github.com/PeterHdd/pcer, would solve this problem –

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Typings can be configured with the `~/.typingsrc` config file. (`~` means your home directory)

After finding this issue on github: https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/120, I was able to hack around this issue by creating `~/.typingsrc` and setting this configuration:

```
{
  "proxy": "http://<server>:<port>",
  "rejectUnauthorized": false
}
```

It also seemed to work without the `proxy` setting, so maybe it was able to pick that up from the environment somewhere.

This is not a true solution, but was enough for `typings` to ignore the corporate firewall issues so that I could continue working. I'm sure there is a better solution out there.

Answer (score 198):

Try

`npm config set strict-ssl false`

This is a alternative shared in this url https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3742

Comment: Is it safe to restrict strict-ssl?

Comment: Is it safe?  Short answer: No.  Long answer, yes, but only if you are on a secure network with a proxy server that does the SSL validation for you.  Speak to your network administrator.

Comment: I had this problem, and this answer did not help me, nor did nfiles answer help...

Comment: Interesting how this might help for some users but after using npm install, revert the process to `true`.

Comment: If you're using yarn: `yarn config set "strict-ssl" false`

Comment: Or, if you can, get off your VPN when you run `npm i`, and keep the `strict-ssl=true`... 

In my particular case, the install couldn't finish without errors regardless of the `strict-ssl` parameter, as long as I was on the VPN. Off the VPN it worked fine regardless of the parameter.

Answer (score 73):

This worked for me:

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Please refer to the NodeJS documentation for usage and warnings:
https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_node_tls_reject_unauthorized_value

Comment: This answer would be better with some explanation or documentation reference.

Comment: I'm still getting this warning message.   (node:47985) Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling certificate verification.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep Error making request.
npm ERR! prepareGitDep Error: SSL Error: UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY

Comment: What helped me is this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39764323/2521806

Answer (score 65):

> There is an issue discussed here which talks about using ca files, but it's a bit beyond my understanding and I'm unsure what to do about it.

This isn't too difficult once you know how! For Windows:

Using Chrome go to the root URL NPM is complaining about (so https://raw.githubusercontent.com in your case). 
Open up dev tools and go to Security-> View Certificate. Check Certification path and make sure your at the top level certificate, if not open that one. Now go to "Details" and export the cert with "Copy to File...".

You need to convert this from DER to PEM. There are several ways to do this, but the easiest way I found was an online tool which should be easy to find with relevant keywords.

Now if you open the key with your favorite text editor you should see

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 

yourkey

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

This is the format you need. You can do this for as many keys as you need, and combine them all into one file. I had to do github and the npm registry keys in my case.

Now just edit your .npmrc to point to the file containing your keys like so

```
cafile=C:\workspace\rootCerts.crt
```

I have personally found this to perform significantly better behind our corporate proxy as opposed to the strict-ssl option. YMMV.

Comment: Best answer IMO as it works(for me) and it doesn't involve bypassing security checks

Comment: Stupid question, is it safe to use an online tool to convert my cert?

Comment: @Neil, Yes it's safe because the certificate contains the *public* key. It doesn't contain the private key that must be kept secret.

Comment: A wellsuited answer if you are behind corporate proxy

Comment: In windows, you can directly export the file as a PEM -- Just select the "Base64 Encoded X.509" version instead of the DER version.  Also, the certificate doesn't contain yourkey.  Instead it contains an X.509 formatted certificate.

Comment: Seems to work on OSX as well!

Comment: Awesome, after so many attempts for my work computer... Finally something that works

Comment: If you're using `brew` on a recent OSX, the cafile is in your brew cellar, e.g. `$HOME/homebrew/Cellar/ca-certificates/2022-07-19_1/share/ca-certificates/cacert.pem`

Comment: I had to use `certfile=C:\Users\myUserName\rootCer.crt`.  `cafile` did not work for me.

Comment: I was struggling a lot but your description was for me that solved the problem  of  "unable to get local issuer certificate" 
Thanks Tim L.

Comment: I am also behind corporate proxy, but this didn't work for me. Can someone please help

Answer (score 35):

Anyone gets this error when 'npm install' is trying to fetch a package from HTTPS server with a self-signed or invalid certificate.

**Quick and insecure solution:**

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Why this solution is insecure?
The above command tells npm to connect and fetch module from server even server do not have valid certificate and server identity is not verified. So if there is a proxy server between npm client and actual server, it provided man in middle attack opportunity to an intruder.

**Secure solution:**

If any module in your package.json is hosted on a server with self-signed CA certificate then npm is unable to identify that server with an available system CA certificates.
So you need to provide CA certificate for server validation with the explicit configuration in .npmrc.
In .npmrc you need to provide cafile, please refer to [more detail about cafile configuration](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#cafile).

```
cafile=./ca-certs.pem
```

In ca-certs file, you can add any number of CA certificates(public) that you required to identify servers. The certificate should be in “Base-64 encoded X.509 (.CER)(PEM)” format.

For example,

```
# cat ca-certs.pem 
DigiCert Global Root CA
=======================
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
CAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAE.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5
========================================
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIE0zCCA7ugAwIBAgIQ......
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Note: once you provide cafile configuration in .npmrc, npm try to identify all server using CA certificate(s) provided in cafile only, it won't check system CA certificate bundles then.
Here's a well-known [public CA authority certificate bundle](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html).

**One other situation when you get this error:**

If you have mentioned Git URL as a dependency in package.json and git is on invalid/self-signed certificate then also npm throws a similar error.
You can fix it with following configuration for git client

```
git config --global http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: If the system is behind the secure proxy of company/organization, this kind of error occurs. And for that secure solution should always be preferred.

Just to add more to this answers. Following commands can be used to set cafile=./ca-certs.pem in npmrc file.

*To set the cafile:*
`npm config set cafile <CERT_FILE_PATH>`

*To verify the set cafile:*
`npm config get cafile`

For more information on how to set config please visit, https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#cafile and https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/config#set

Comment: When your internet access via secure proxy, npm client gets certificate of site from proxy, In this case if your host OS trust the proxy certificate then its not a issue, other wise you need to configure proxy CA certificate for trust.

Answer (score 22):

If you're on a corporate computer, it likely has custom certificates (note the plural on that). It took a while to figure out, but I've been using this little script to grab everything and configure Node, NPM, Yarn, AWS, and Git (turns out the solution is similar for most tools). Stuff this in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` or similar location:

```sh
function setup-certs() {
  # place to put the combined certs
  local cert_path="$HOME/.certs/all.pem"
  local cert_dir=$(dirname "${cert_path}")
  [[ -d "${cert_dir}" ]] || mkdir -p "${cert_dir}"
  # grab all the certs
  security find-certificate -a -p /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain > "${cert_path}"
  security find-certificate -a -p /Library/Keychains/System.keychain >> "${cert_path}"
  # configure env vars for commonly used tools
  export GIT_SSL_CAINFO="${cert_path}"
  export AWS_CA_BUNDLE="${cert_path}"
  export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="${cert_path}"
  # add the certs for npm and yarn
  # and since we have certs, strict-ssl can be true
  npm config set -g cafile "${cert_path}"
  npm config set -g strict-ssl true
  yarn config set cafile "${cert_path}" -g
  yarn config set strict-ssl true -g
}
setup-certs
```

You can then, at any time, run `setup-certs` in your terminal. Note that if you're using Nvm to manage Node versions, you'll need to run this for each version of Node. I've noticed that some corporate certificates get rotated every so often. Simply re-running `setup-certs` fixes all that.

You'll notice that most answers suggest setting `strict-ssl` to `false`. Please don't do that. Instead use the `setup-certs` solution to use the actual certificates.

Comment: Out of all the solutions I have tried, this worked for me right away. Thanks @tjklemz

Answer (score 10):

My problem was that my company proxy was getting in the way.  The solution here was to identify the Root CA / certificate chain of our proxy, (on mac) export it from the keychain in .pem format, then export a variable for node to use.

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/your/CA/cert.pem
```

Answer (score 9):

For anyone coming to this from macOS:

Somehow, npm hasn't picked up correct certificates file location, and I needed to explicitly point to it:

```
$ echo "cafile=$(brew --prefix)/share/ca-certificates/cacert.pem" >> ~/.npmrc
$ cat ~/.npmrc # for ARM macOS
cafile=/opt/homebrew/share/ca-certificates/cacert.pem
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for those on macOS with `node` installed via `brew`. Not sure if it's a ARM-specific issue (hinted at in this answer), but I was on that platform when I encountered the issue.

Comment: This did not work for me on intel macbook, but I did a similar thing with `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS="/path/to/ca-certificates/cacert.pem"` in my `~/.zshrc`.

Answer (score 7):

There are different reason for this issue and workaround is different depends on situation. Listing here few workaround (note: it is insecure workaround so please check your organizational policies before trying).

[image]

Step 1: Test and ensure internet is working on machine with command prompt and same url is accessible directly which fails by NPM. There are many tools for this, like curl, wget etc. If you are using windows then try telnet or curl for windows.

Step 2: Set strict ssl to false by using below command

`npm -g config set strict-ssl false`

Step 3: Set reject unauthorized TLS to no by using below command:

`export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

In case of windows (or can use screen to set environment variable):

`set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

Step 4: Add unsafe param in installation command e.g.

`npm i -g abc-package@1.0 --unsafe-perm true`

Answer (score 7):

Once you have your certificate (cer or pem file), add it as a system variable like in the screenshot below.

This is the secure way of solving the problem, rather than disabling SSL. You have to tell npm or whatever node tool you're using to use these certificates when establing an SSL connection using the environment variable `NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS`.

This is common when you're behind a corporate firewall or proxy. You can find the correct certificate by just inspecting the security tab in Chrome when visiting a page while on your company's VPN or proxy and exporting the certificate through the "Manage Computer Certificates" window in Windows.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Add:

```
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
```

Source: [Ignore invalid self-signed ssl certificate in node.js with https.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request)

Comment: managed to bypass my `npx` command error with this, thank you:
`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 npx @api-platform/client-generator https://localhost src/ -g react`

Comment: In PowerShell, use `$env:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0`

Answer (score 4):

I have encountered the same issue. This command didn't work for me either:

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

After digging deeper, I found out that this link was block by our IT admin.

```
http://registry.npmjs.org/npm
```

So if you are facing the same issue, make sure this link is accessible to your browser first.

Comment: The above link is accessible and I have also used the set strict-ssl false command but it is not working still

Comment: ZScaler was blocking us. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In case you use `yarn`:

`yarn config set strict-ssl false`

Answer (score 2):

There is another option I would recommend to check before disabling SSL/TLS security or switching to a http:// url:

npm allows to configure a file which contains all trusted root CA certificates. If this file is present and does not contain the necessary root AC certificates this can also end up in a `unable to get local issuer certificate` error.

Therefore you should check if the command

```
npm config get cafile
```

returns a configured file. By default it should return `null` (no special CA certificate configured). If it returns something different examine the mentioned file and if you want to remove the setting you can open the npm configuration file and remove the `cafile` entry:

```
npm config edit
```

Answer (score 1):

**A disclaimer: This solution is less secure, bad practice, don't do this.**
I had a duplicate error message--I'm behind a corporate VPN/firewall.  I was able to resolve this issue by adding a .typingsrc file to my user directory (`C:\Users\MyUserName\.typingsrc` in windows).  Of course, anytime you're circumventing SSL you should be yapping to your sys admins to fix the certificate issue.

Change the registry URL from *https* to *http*, and as seen in [nfiles' answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36628311/2341818) above, set *rejectUnauthorized*  to *false*.

**.typingsrc** (placed in project directory or in user root directory)

```
{
     "rejectUnauthorized": false,
     "registryURL": "http://api.typings.org/"
}
```

Optionally add your github token (I didn't find success until I had added this too.)

```
{
    "rejectUnauthorized": false,
    "registryURL": "http://api.typings.org/",
    "githubToken": "YourGitHubToken"
}
```

See instructions for setting up your github token at https://github.com/blog/1509-personal-api-tokens

Answer (score 1):

**Well this is not a right answer but can be consider as a quick workaround. Right answer is turn off Strict SSL.**

I am having the same error

PhantomJS not found on PATH
Downloading https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/releases/download/v2.1.1/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip
Saving to C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip
Receiving...

Error making request.
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket. (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38)

So the after reading the error.

Just downloaded the file manually and placed it on the required path.
i.e

```
C:\Users\Sam\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\
```

This solved my problem.

```
    PhantomJS not found on PATH                                                                                                
Download already available at C:\Users\sam\AppData\Local\Temp\phantomjs\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows.zip                    
Verified checksum of previously downloaded file                                                                            
Extracting zip contents
```

Comment: Worked for me, not sure why nothing else was. I'm still only getting set up so I'll try a more permanent solution after I'm up and running. Good idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

reinstall ca-certificates is work for me

```bash
# OSX
brew install ca-certificates
```

Answer (score 1):

```
npm config set strict-ssl false

and then install angular again 

npm install -g @angular/cli

once angular is installed then set 

npm config set strict-ssl true

this is safe
```

Answer (score 0):

On FreeBSD, this error can be produced because the `cafile` path is set to a symlink instead of the absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

On macOs I faced the same problem and in my case my node-gyp just didn't see my .pem file.

Next helped me:

```
sudo npm install -g node-gyp

node-gyp configure

rm -rf ~/.node-gyp ~/.npm ~/.config

node-gyp configure --cafile="/path/to/myCertificate.pem"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's the little things. My npm process is owned by root, so I tried the following:

```
sudo npm install stuff
```

I forgot that root doesn't have my user's npm configuration, so I needed to add the -E flag to allow root to use my configuration:

```
sudo -E npm install stuff
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with privileges, but with the server's certificate from the client point of view

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost all above steps. Somehow none of them worked for me. I added environment variable and restarted powershell it worked.
[image]