# gyp ERR, Npm is unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install, node-gyp

I am working on clean Windows 10 installation. Only thing is cygwin that I installed to get unix commands in the cmd.

When I type `npm install -g @angular/cli` it downloads the necessary files but I receive an error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1092:38)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:185:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:610:8)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:440:38)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.15063
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\@angular\\cli\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v6.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
```

I edited npm config file like 'npm config edit'. In the opened file I added the following settings:

```
strict-ssl=false
http_proxy=null
proxy=null
```

But this does not work and I still receive the same error. What more, `npm install` also breaks with the same result.

Comment: are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install error - unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494336/npm-install-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I had the same issue.
The following solved my issue

- Windows

`set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

- Linux

`export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`

Then `npm install` again

You can refer [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/695) for more info.

Comment: Good as a temporary fix for development, but this should be avoided for deployment because it exposes you to man-in-the-middle attacks.  Better is to properly set up SSL in your VM or container.

Comment: On my powershell I need to set it with 'set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED 0'

Comment: This turns off the security provided by the Certificate Authority to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: This did not work for me, even though I can see the command mentioned in warnings as making the HTTPS requests insecure.   Similar settings for npm worked, but gyp still gives this same garbage

Answer (score 15):

The answer from @Emon is correct, however for Linuz users the command obviously would be:

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Edit: as pointed out in the comments this should be used only as temporary fix for development, but it exposes you to man-in-the-middle attacks. The long-term solution should be to properly set up SSL certificates.

Comment: This turns off the security provided by the Certificate Authority to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: Thanks it solved the issue for me `export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` on centOS

Answer (score 3):

Find the certificate bundle on your system and then set the environment variable NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS to that path.

```
find / -name *.crt

/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
/usr/share/ca-certificates/full_bundle.crt
/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DigiCert_Assured_ID_Root_CA.crt
/usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/E-Tugra_Certification_Authority.crt
...
```

You should get lots of results so you will have to look through them to determine the correct crt file. then:

```
export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/usr/share/ca-certificates/full_bundle.crt
```

Comment: This does no turns off the security provided by the Certificate Authority to prevent man-in-the-middle attacks.  However, the certificates will become stale (not the latest version) and then expire.  At that point, you will not be able to install / update.  So, this is a short-term workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your machine is being blocked by security - possibly by a firewall or by software installed on your machine - from downloading files into the _cacert folder.  I got around this by running "npm install" on another machine that was not being blocked and then using the _cacert folder from that machine on my machine.

The same issue also exists for ca certificates that you already have because they usually have an expiration date.  You will get a warning message like "Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation." when doing an npm install or update in such cases. Eventually, your certificate will expire and you will blocked altogether.

This is an awkward workaround. The only real long time solution is work with the security provider to stop blocking new ca certificates from being downloaded.