# Correct way to handle "Unable to Get Local Issuer Certificate" in an electron app

Tags: node.js, ssl, ssl-certificate, electron

A node/electron app gets deployed on the end user's machine. It tries to make an HTTPS request to a server. Depending on the user's network setup, this may work fine, or Node may throw the error `"Unable to Get Local Issuer Certificate"`. As far as I understand, this happens when the client is behind a proxy with SSL interception or something similar.

I know SO and github are full of questions like this. But the only generic "solution" I could find is breaking SSL entirely either at process level:

```
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0
```

or at request level:

```
rejectUnauthorized: "false"
```

There's also the option to somehow specify the correct certificate when making the HTTP request. But it seems to almost require custom setup for every user and I haven't found any examples of doing it in a generic way.

**1. Why is this issue specific to Node apps, while every other app on the computer works fine?**

**2. Can it be fixed in a general and cross-platform way?**

Comment: your try to connect to server over https, where the server should have ssl certificates configured in nginx/apache/nodejs. Also client should provide proper certificates while making request to server

Comment: This issue doesn't depend on the server. It only happens when the client is behind an intercepting proxy.

Comment: This is the best description of this issue I've seen and also the questions I have regarding the "solutions". I am going to try "certificate pinning". I do not think it's the client's issue, however, as other HTTPS invocations are working fine. @VikashSingh I do not understand how a client is expected to supply certificates to a server.

Comment: @astreltsov Mine is a server-to-server app on the same subnet, no proxies.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way is as described in this answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726189/49942

In summary:

- Guess which site it's trying to access -- probably `github.com` in order to download a release of the Electron binaries e.g. from https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/tag/v28.2.0
- Navigate to that page using Chrome, find and export the page's root certificate

  [image]

  For me this creates a `*.crt` file in PEM file format, my Downloads directory
- Add this file's path to npm's `cafile` config option.