# How to install electron without using npm command?

Tags: installation, electron

Please let me know, how to install electron without using npm.  I am using windows 10 , 64 bit OS. I have tried to find option with documentation but not getting detailed step by step guide for this.

Comment: why do you not want to use npm? You could always download the zips I suppose an unpack them

Comment: Behind firewall, it gives error "Unable to get local issuer certificate". On electronJS documentation page, I have read  one option to install manually. But not getting proper details. As there are multiple zip files listed. I want to install electron for windows 10 , 64 bit. Can someone help for this , which zip file to be downloaded manually and steps to install after that ?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "installing electron"? You can install an electron application. If it's packed you do not need npm or node.

If you want to write an electron application you will need the packages and therefore npm. Only way of doing it without would be installing the dependencies manually which would be extremely difficult and time consuming. Furthermore without npm you cannot test or pack your app. So that would be quite useless.

Why do you not want to use npm?

Comment: Behind firewall, it gives error "Unable to get local issuer certificate". On electronJS documentation page, I have read one option to install manually. But not getting proper details. As there are multiple zip files listed. I want to install electron for windows 10 , 64 bit. Can someone help for this , which zip file to be downloaded manually and steps to install after that

Comment: Again: Electron is not something you can install. That's not who it works. Do you mean installing node and npm?

Comment: No. I am referring this command . npm install --save-dev electron.  This is not working.

Comment: Tried this? (there is more then one answer to this question):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494336/npm-install-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate

Comment: I tried the options which you suggested earlier , but it is still giving error. I was referring this link https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/installation#troubleshooting , here it is mentioned option to install manually, but steps are not clear. I want to do it for windows 10 , 64 bit. Which binary to download and steps after downloading it , I want to know.