# gcloud init ssl errors on mac (M1)

Tags: macos, ssl, gcloud

I cant seem to initialize the gcloud

heres the log

[image]

the mac is new. anyone has any ideas?

Comment: What does `gcloud info --run-diagnostics --verbosity=debug` show?

Comment: 1) Do not use images. Copy and paste the text into your question. 2) You have a certificate problem. Try **brew install curl ca-certificates** which worked on older Macs. I am not sure about the correct command M1s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be many possible reasons like :

- Networking configurations and any proxy that can cause the handshake
  to fail.
- Antivirus, firewalls, or any other software that are preventing the
  traffic.
- Corporate certificates are being used.
- A real SSL issue (there could be a captive portal in between you and
  Google)
- A Python version/system libraries with SSL issues (2.7.11 seems to
  work for most users, but you can try different minor versions, like
  2.7.10 or 2.7.9)

In order to Authenticate whether this error has occurred due to proxy or not, you can try running below commands:

```
$ curl https://dl.google.com/ 

**Output**: <a href="https://www.google.com/chrome"> Found </a>
```

If you get a different output from the above mentioned one then, you're **behind a proxy or portal**.

**Solutions :**

- Try running `npm config set strict-ssl false` This is an alternative
  shared in this url https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3742.  I
  wouldn’t recommend this but it's a short and quick solution.
- Also have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726189/15803365) on how the user added certificates
  manually to perform significantly better behind corporate proxy as
  opposed to the strict-ssl option. This solution is for Windows, but a
  user confirmed in the comment it is for OSX as well.