# Installing Prisma in my Next.js app doesn't work

Tags: node.js, npm, next.js, prisma

I'm building a Next.js application and wanted to install Prisma on it to connect a PostgreSQL database.
But when I'm installing Prisma I got the following error:

`> Downloading Prisma engines for Node-API for windows [                    ] 0%Error: request to https://binaries.prisma.sh/all_commits/6b0aef69b7cdfc787f822ecd7cdc76d5f1991584/windows/query_engine.dll.node.gz.sha256 failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate`

I don't know why it happens cause when I'm clicking on the link the file is downloading on my computer.
So, if anybody know how I can fix this error, or have an alternative to connect a PostgreSQL database to my application it would be great!

- Windows 10
- Node version: **20.4.1**
- Npm version: **9.4.0**
- Next.js version:
  **13.4.9**
- Prisma version: **^5.0.0**

Thank you,

Have a good day!

Comment: Can you try changing your network and see if you get the same error?

Comment: @NurulSundarani I can't for some reason, I will try to find an alternative to Prisma!

Comment: Can you try setting this environment variable? Hopefully it should fix the issue for you.
https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/19323#issuecomment-1560362444

Comment: If none of the above works for you, you can also try following the recommendation in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494336/npm-install-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)