# Error 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'

Tags: node.js, discord.js, local

I hope you can help me.
I've been having the following error for a few days in the 'node .' command:

```
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
            ^

Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
    at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12) {
  code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY'
}
```

I have already tried different ways of resolving what I found in the communities, but so far none have been effective.

NPM Version: v10.4.0 | Node Version: v20.11.0. | Discod.JS Version: v14.14.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm install error - unable to get local issuer certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36494336/npm-install-error-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate)

Comment: It didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling strict SSL will likely solve the issue and is safe as long as you are on a secure network.

`npm config set strict-ssl false`

Comment: It didn't solve the problem.