# Unable to call EWS when require ssl is true

Tags: node.js, ssl, exchangewebservices, ngrok

I have Exchange server 2010 installed in development environment. I am trying to call EWS services form node js web application which is also in dev environment.

When i set require ssl on EWS web site on IIS manager, I get 403 error.
Which it normal because my URL endpoint in application was with http, exactly: http://192.168.50.192/EWS/Exchange.asmx

But when I try with url https://192.168.50.192/EWS/Exchange.asmx 
that is https, I am getting timeout.

I am entering this url on web form and then programmatically compose SOAP request which I sent to this URL.

I have tried to start [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) and use whole application with https locally, but I get the same result.

If ssl certificate is the issue, ngrok has valid certificate.

Please advise.

Do I need to apply any additional settings on IIS?

Comment: Can you share the code that makes the request? Also, what are you using to generate the server - express, Node's native HTTPS? Would there be any intermediate certificates in the chain?

Answer (score 2):

Could you inspect the error details, or do you have a log that you can check ?

By reading the issues, there at least two things that could lead to the issue, if your applications are not sharing the same domain you could be having an issue with the same domain policy and for that you may fix it with CORS policy.

if the issue is not related to SSL certificate, your issue may be related to CORS policy ([How to allow CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067966/how-to-allow-cors-in-express-node-js) , https://senecacd.wordpress.com/2013/02/15/enabling-cors-on-a-node-js-server-same-origin-policy-issue/)

if that is related to SSL then you need to create a self signed SSL Certificate and try with it. (you need to disable the SSL peer validation though.)

Comment: Microsoft has not implemented CORS for Exchange Servers, no calls can be made which usage CORS.

Answer (score 0):

You can try two things:

1. generate SSL certificate in the host name/fqdn (exchserver/exch.domain.com) format rather than with IP address. import this ssl certificate and chain using Exchange Admin Center/IIS. Also trust this certificate in your client computer where you are running the nodejs application.
2. instruct nodejs to ignore server certificate by putting this line before all your codes `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";` taken from [Ignore invalid self-signed ssl certificate in node.js with https.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request)

if you are working on EWS extensively in your nodejs app you should consider using [`ews-javascript-api node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ews-javascript-api) module