# Nodejs request to a web service with .p12 certificate

Tags: node.js, ssl, openssl, certificate, p12

So, the title is pretty straightforward. I want to consume a web service from a company and I got .cer and .p12 files. Supposedly, I should use .p12 when making a request. I've imported .cer into windows and I can make requests with postman easily. But when I'm trying to do a request with node.js, I get errors. Here's the code, I'm using `request` module:

```
var headersOpt = {
    "content-type": "application/json",
};

var options = {
    url: 'https://some-url/api',
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/myCert.p12'),
    headers: headersOpt
};

request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(body);
});
```

I get this error:

```
{ Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
    at Object.createSecureContext (_tls_common.js:89:17)
    at Object.exports.connect (_tls_wrap.js:1048:48)
    at Agent.createConnection (https.js:111:22)
    at Agent.createSocket (_http_agent.js:224:26)
    at Agent.addRequest (_http_agent.js:192:10)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:256:16)
    at Object.request (http.js:39:10)
    at Object.request (https.js:239:15)
    at Request.start (D:\parser\node_modules\request\request.js:748:32)
    at Request.end (D:\parser\node_modules\request\request.js:1512:10)
  opensslErrorStack:
   [ 'error:140DC009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:PEM lib' ] }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use `pfx` property in [`agentOptions`](https://github.com/request/request#using-optionsagentoptions) for pkcs12 format :

```
'use strict';

const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    url: 'https://some-url/api',
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    agentOptions: {
        pfx: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/certs/myCert.p12'),
        passphrase: ''
    }
};

request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(error);
    console.log(response);
    console.log(body);
});
```

If your certificate is self signed, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request)

Comment: thanks, this did kind of solve the issue. it still did not work, and I tried this version a couple of times before, but then I figured I got the wrong password. Anyways, thanks for pointing out the correct approach so that I could focus on other things, rather than trying different combinations!

Comment: When I used the above, I’m getting fs.readFileSync is not a function.

Comment: Instead of using fs.readFileSync, is there an alternative? I am getting its not a function. The fs object is empty when I log it out

Comment: There is so little documentation out there about using pfx files with requests.  I'd give you a hundred upvotes if I could, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The request API in the other comment from Bertrand Martel is deprecated and therefore not secure, you can also use axios to achieve the same thing:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const axios = require('axios');
const https = require('https');

const response = await axios.request({
    url: *URL_HERE*,
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json",
    },
    data: JSON.stringify({
        *YOUR_DATA_HERE*
    }),
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        passphrase: *PASSPHRASE_HERE*,
        pfx: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '\\..\\certificates\\certificate.p12'),
    })
});
```