# Download-file npm for https

Tags: node.js, npm

Using **Download-file** `npm` from https protocol shows the below error,

> Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

I added the below options,

```
 rejectUnauthorized: false,
 requestCert: true,
 agent: false
```

still not working

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignore invalid self-signed ssl certificate in node.js with https.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request)

Comment: when i run the url in browser, it downloads a pem file for me...

Comment: I same i have to do it via API

Comment: All i want is, my API has to download that pem file when i run that url

Comment: /var options = {
    directory: "./New",
    filename: "New.pem",
 rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: false,
    agent: false
 
}
 
download(url, options, function(err){
    if (err) throw err
    console.log("downloaded")
 
})

Comment: Using Download-file npm from https protocol shows the below error,

Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain