# Javascript: 'Self signed certificate' error during API call

Tags: javascript, certificate

I'm automating some API calls in Javascript and a few days ago this error started appearing out of nowhere.

```
base.js:383
  1) Test API call
base.js:266
       Fourth test:
     FetchError: request to https://api.qa.xx.xxxx.com:443/mobile/v2/subscribers failed, reason: self signed certificate in certificate chain
      at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (node_modules/node-fetch/lib/index.js:1393:11)
      at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:387:9)
      at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:64:8)
      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

I have spent countless hours trying to find a solution but nothing works. I've re-cloned the entire repo and everything. Does anybody know how to solve this?

What I did before this started happening:

1. Installed npm config
2. Installed mongodb client

I've uninstalled since

Comment: Not a lot here to look at really, but as default if you connect in node using a self signed certificate, it will error unless you turn of the check.   Maybe this will help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request

Answer (score 18):

Apparently there is a [related issue](https://github.com/bitinn/node-fetch/issues/19) with two solutions,

pass an http agent, setting `rejectUnauthorized`

```
const https = require("https");
const agent = new https.Agent({
  rejectUnauthorized: false
})
fetch(myUrl, { agent })
```

set an env var in your package.json start script

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED="0" npm start
```

or use a `process.env` var

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```