# How can I convert this Curl call to Javascript/React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curl, ssl-certificate

I have a curl call that looks like this:

```
curl \
-v \
-X POST \
-k \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{
    "mydata": "XXXXX"
}' \
"https://localhost:11000/myEndpoint"
```

It works. I get a 200 response. But when I remove the `-k` flag, it fails with this error:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate

So I know that the `-k` flag is required.

Now I'm trying to convert this curl to Javascript/React. But when I do this in React, it fails:

```
const response = await fetch(
  'https://localhost:11000/myEndpoint',
  {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ mydata: 'XXXXX' })
  },
)
```

Here is the error in the browser console:

> POST https://localhost:11000/myEndpoint net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I believe this error is because the Javascript/React is not doing the equivalent of a `-k`.
How can I make it mimic the `-k` behavior of Curl?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958516/javascript-self-signed-certificate-error-during-api-call

Comment: @johnSmith That's about Node.js, not the browser.

Comment: Another option would be to ajaxcall call a serverside script hosted on your domain that does the curl request and returns the response

Answer (score 3):

There's no way to have a `fetch()` (or XHR, or any other) call directly do what `-k` (also known as **`--insecure`**) does.

You will need to tell your browser to trust that self-signed certificate.

In general, you can do that for a single session by navigating to https://localhost:11000/ and accepting the "Yes, I know what I'm doing, I know this is insecure" prompt that'll likely show up.

For more permanent solutions, you can search the web for e.g. "trust self-signed certificate YOUR BROWSER HERE"...

Answer (score 0):

AKX's response is correct. Had a similar issue, I believe the way described is valid on chrome. For firefox you have to [trust the certificate through the browser](https://superuser.com/questions/1740221/can-i-make-firefox-automatically-trust-self-signed-certs-for-a-given-hostname-ip).

That being said, you can basically use axios instead of fetch and pass as options:

```
   httpsAgent: new https.Agent({rejectUnauthorized: false})
```

However, this will not work if you are using webpack > 5 (will be printed in the console as an error). To make it work in dev environment, you should do the following:

- Install the packages https, https-browserify, stream-http and include them in webpack.config.js as polyfills:

  ```
   resolve: { 
       fallback: {
           "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),
            "http": require.resolve("stream-http")
       }
   }
  ```
- Install also (npm install): buffer, url
- Run the project and should work

For reasons why this approach should always be avoided in prod (sometimes maybe in dev also) please check the first answer here: [How to configure axios to use SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363855/how-to-configure-axios-to-use-ssl-certificate)