# How to create a https rest client using nodejs?

Tags: node.js, rest, https

I am trying to get data from https endpoints using [node-rest-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-rest-client)

```
const Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;

const client = new Client();

client.get("https://myapi.com/data.xml", function (data, response) {
    // parsed response body as js object
    console.log(data);
    // raw response
    console.log(response);
});
```

but I got this error:

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1049:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:631:8)
```

Comment: https://github.com/Daplie/node-ssl-root-cas/issues/26

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem

Comment: Do you care about certificate validation? If you don't see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request) answer.