# Self-signed cert for gRPC on Flutter

Tags: ssl, flutter, dart, grpc, self-signed

I have a Flutter app that communicates with a server using gRPC. The server is using a self-signed certificate for TLS. I have added the certificate to my Flutter app, and this works on Android. However on iOS I get CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error. Does iOS just not allow self-signed certificates?

I am setting up my gRPC client as follows:

```
    var cert = await rootBundle.load('assets/cert.crt');
    var creds = ChannelCredentials.secure(
        certificates: cert.buffer.asUint8List().toList()
    );
    var channel = ClientChannel(
        host,
        port: port,
        options: new ChannelOptions(credentials: creds));
    return GrpcClient(channel);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an obvious solution on iOS for adding a trusted, self-signed root CA. Since production will likely have a publically trusted CA, you can work around by disabling TLS verification for development *only*.

Here's the relevant snippet of my [full example repo](https://github.com/AndiDog/flutter_grpc_selfsigned):

```dart
Future<ClientChannel> makeChannel() async {
  final caCert = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/pki/ca/ca.crt');

  return ClientChannel(
    'localhost',
    port: 13100,
    options: ChannelOptions(
      credentials: ChannelCredentials.secure(
        certificates: utf8.encode(caCert),

        // --- WORKAROUND FOR SELF-SIGNED DEVELOPMENT CA ---
        onBadCertificate: (certificate, host) => host == 'localhost:13100',
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

In this case, my server is listening on `localhost:13100`.

Comment: Thanks, this is essentially what I have ended up doing.

Comment: hey @AndiDog, my app behaves different depending on if i add `onBadCertificate` or not...without it, i get: `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate` and with it, i get: `SSLV3_ALERT_BAD_CERTIFICATE`...both for the same `.perm` file....any clue what can be wrong?

Comment: Debug the alert in Wireshark or in the logs? Since you see a difference, I assume the desired effect actually works, but you possibly still got a server-side alert for some other reason (e.g. bad client certificate).

Comment: @JamesTan No. But which Flutter platform runs node? Are you cross-compiling server-side Dart code to node.js? Then maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request helps.

Comment: sorry i was using nodejs as client side, not flutter. havent try that reference, but i got this working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62108009/grpc-node-client-allow-signed-certificate

Answer (score 0):

The following was adapted from:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dart/issues/134

It allows for specifying a custom (or self-signed) CA cert, client certificates, and/or a custom domain:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';


class CustomChannelCredentials extends ChannelCredentials {
  final String caCert;
  final String? clientCert;
  final String? clientKey;

  CustomChannelCredentials({
    required this.caCert,
    this.clientCert,
    this.clientKey,
    String? authority, // Custom domain used by server cert
  }) : super.secure(
     authority: authority,
     onBadCertificate: (cert, host) {
        // This is a work-around for iOS, it seems self-signed certs are not being properly verified;
        return host == '<the common name used self-signed CA>';
      },      
   );

  @override
  SecurityContext get securityContext {
    final context = SecurityContext(
      withTrustedRoots: false, // We want to specify a custom CA cert
    );
    context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(utf8.encode(caCert));
    context.setAlpnProtocols(supportedAlpnProtocols, false);

    if (clientCert != null) {
      context.useCertificateChainBytes(utf8.encode(clientCert!));
    }
    if (clientKey != null) {
      context.usePrivateKeyBytes(utf8.encode(clientKey!));
    }
    return context;
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
final channel = ClientChannel(
 serverAddress,
  port: serverPort,
  options: ChannelOptions(
    credentials: CustomChannelCredentials(
      caCert: selfSignedCaCertPem,
      // clientCert: clientCertPem,
      // clientKey: clientKeyPem,
      authority: 'localhost',
    ),
  ),
);
```