# #grpc node client allow signed certificate

Tags: grpc, grpc-node

i have a self signed grpc service on server, and got it working for dart server with dart client.
But i could not figure how to bypass or allow self signed certificate for node client..
I've tried this:

```
const sslCreds = await grpc.credentials.createSsl(
    fs.readFileSync('./ssl/client.crt'),
    null, // privatekey
    null, // certChain
    {
      checkServerIdentity: function(host, info) {
  console.log('verify?', host, info);
  if (
    host.startsWith('127.0.0.1') ||
    host.startsWith('logs.example.com')
  ) {
    return true;
  }
  console.log('verify other?', host);
  return true;
},
    },
  );

  // sslCreds.options.checkServerIdentity = checkCert;

  const gLogClient = new synagieLogGrpc.LoggerClient(
    'host:port',
    sslCreds,
  );
```

but when i call, my validation checkServerIdentity did not call.

anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after checking out multiple github issues, and testing for 2 days,
this code below works.
critical point is, actual host:port is the destination, which could be localhost. but we will need to override the ssl target name with the actual generated ssl domain.

for sample of tls generation:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/1451

```
const host = 'localhost';
const port = 8088;;
const hostPort = `${host}:${port}`;
const gLogClient = new synagieLogGrpc.LoggerClient(hostPort, sslCreds, {
  'grpc.ssl_target_name_override': 'actual_tlsdomain.example.com',
});
```