# Unable to verify first certificate error in Node js on a particular network

Tags: node.js, express, ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-storage

I am getting unable to verify first certificate error when I am trying to connect to IBM Cloud Object Storage using Node.js sdk on a work network. However I don't get this error when using other networks such as my phone's and Public Wi-Fi.

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1321:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:794:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:608:12) {
  message: 'unable to verify the first certificate',
  code: 'NetworkingError',
  region: 'us-east-1',
  hostname: '***************.s3.us-south.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud',
  retryable: true,
  time: 2020-02-03T06:58:45.578Z
}
```

Comment: can you post the full hostname to the bucket?  It is hard to debug what is going on without that...  As a quick test could you try this to see if it unblocks you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21961005/3817025

Comment: @JeffSloyer It seems to be working now without me doing any changes. Same way the error was raised the first time(all of a sudden, out of nowhere).