# Error: unable to verify the first certificate in Nestjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, nestjs

On my local machine, my nestjs application is running on port 3000 and I have one controller with two endpoints:

```js
@Get()
getAll() {
 return this.httpService.get('https://localhost:3000/something')
}

@Get('something')
getSomething() {
 return [1, 2, 3];
}
```

When I try to run the `getAll` endpoint, I am getting `Error: unable to verify the first certificate`. I understand that the issue is to do with a SSL certificate, which would probably not be an issue on a remote environment with a properly issued SSL certificate, so I am just wondering if there is a way to get around this locally?

Comment: Looks like this is a duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request so please try it.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of doing such a thing in a real app, please don't! Instead, move all the logic to another layer (service) and then you can reuse service logic in both controller methods if you need.

Comment: I am doing this to mock an external API and I just do not want to spin up a separate app for this.

Comment: By service, I meant provider in NestJS, not a dedicated app...