# Self signed certificate error when fetching API locally

Tags: javascript, node.js, asp.net-web-api, certificate, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple `.NET Core WebAPI` with no authentication. I added Cors with default policy. I have no problem connecting and fetching data from my React website or Postman (everything runs locally on my machine). Now I'm trying to fetch data from that API in super simple `node` application and I'm getting this error:

```
file:///Users/aw/Projects/TestNodeApp/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:94
            reject(new FetchError(`request to ${request.url} failed, reason: ${error.message}`, 'system', error));
                   ^

FetchError: request to https://localhost:5001/api/teams failed, reason: self signed certificate
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (file:///Users/aw/Projects/TestNodeApp/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:94:11)
    at ClientRequest.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:394:28)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  type: 'system',
  errno: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT',
  code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT',
  erroredSysCall: undefined
}
```

This is my whole `node` application:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

async function fetchTeams() {
  const response = await fetch('https://localhost:5001/api/teams', { method: 'GET' });
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}

(async () => {
  console.log('Process started');
  const teams = await fetchTeams();
  console.log(teams);
})().finally(() => {
  console.log('Process finished');
});
```

What does it mean? What Am I missing?

Btw. It works fine, when I'm fetching Github API, like this:

```
async function fetchGithub() {
  const response = await fetch('https://api.github.com/users/Microsoft');
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

So I assume, something is missing in the API. Something that my React website doesn't need, that node app needs.

Thanks for help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request

Answer (score 5):

You can use this command to set the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` environment variable:

```
export NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
```

Comment: Or on Windows (using Powershell) this might look like `$env:NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`.

Answer (score 0):

I opened my node start file/js file where you are calling API and put there the following line of code:

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

If you want to apply this rule only to a test/development environment, you can try doing this:

```
if ("development" == app.get("env")) {
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using next.js

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 next dev",
    ...
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Try trusting the self signed certificate with `dotnet dev-certs`

```
dotnet dev-certs https --trust
```

For more details please visit [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/core/additional-tools/self-signed-certificates-guide#create-a-self-signed-certificate).