# fetchError: unable to verify the self-signed certificate along with net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID with put method

Tags: node.js, axios, next.js, fetch-api

I am using a next js node server as my app. And a ngnix as my https server with self-signed certificate in which my API node server is at behind.

But I am getting a self-signed certificate error.

[image]

So, in my next js , I will contact the https server either by fetch and axios. for example.

[image]

[image]

Is there a easy way on how to get ride of it without buying SSL from real CA?

What I have tried:

This problem couldn't be by pass thru chrome insecure content enabling since it is a server error.

I am guessing this could be achieved from either setting node server / fetch or axios. But I am so new on this kind of problem.

**second update**

```
process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
```

works to get rid of the fetch error:

But now it shown this error with put method:

> net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

[image]

What I have done is to put `process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;` on every api call.

For example

```
   try {
      process.env["NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED"] = 0;
      const res = await axios.put(url);
     
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

I am still looking for a solution.

Comment: Please post relevant code as text and not images.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore invalid self-signed ssl certificate in node.js with https.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request)

Comment: not yet, please , seems this only work with fetch error. But will keep looking for solution. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try adding httpsAgent in your fetch call

```
const https = require('https');
const httpsAgent = new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  });
const response = await fetch("https://localhost/api", {
 
    // Adding method type
    method: "POST",
 
    // Adding body or contents to send
    body: JSON.stringify(
    {data:"data"}),
     
    // Adding headers to the request
    headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    agent: httpsAgent,
})
```

It worked for me

Comment: has not worked for me using Next 12 GetServerSideProps and .net core 6 c# MVC API