# How to solve Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain i VS code?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

I am having a react js project. i tried npm i.
It results in a error.

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\55393\Desktop\Rapidx_Documentation\website\node_modules\fast-folder-size
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node get-sysinternals-du.js
npm ERR! node:events:368
npm ERR!       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
npm ERR!       ^
npm ERR!

npm ERR! Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain

npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1530:34)
npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)

npm ERR!     at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:944:8)

npm ERR!     at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:725:12)

npm ERR! Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
npm ERR!
at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:447:9)

npm ERR!     at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:390:28)

npm ERR!     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)

npm ERR!     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)

npm ERR!     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {

npm ERR!   code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'

npm ERR! }

Is there a solution for this?

i have also attached package.json file below.

{
"scripts": {
"examples": "docusaurus-examples",
"start": "docusaurus start",
"build": "docusaurus build",
"serve": "docusaurus serve",
"publish-gh-pages": "docusaurus-publish",
"write-translations": "docusaurus-write-translations",
"version": "docusaurus-version",
"rename-version": "docusaurus-rename-version",
"swizzle": "docusaurus swizzle",
"deploy": "docusaurus deploy",
"docusaurus": "docusaurus"
},
"engines": {
"node": "v17.6.0"
},
"dependencies": {
"@azure/msal-browser": "^2.28.0",
"@azure/msal-react": "^1.4.4",
"@docusaurus/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@docusaurus/plugin-client-redirects": "^2.1.0",
"@docusaurus/plugin-content-docs": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@docusaurus/preset-classic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
"@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
"@mui/material": "^5.10.3",
"axios": "^0.27.2",
"bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
"chart.js": "^3.8.0",
"clsx": "^1.1.1",
"docker": "^1.0.0",
"docusaurus": "^1.14.7",
"docusaurus-lunr-search": "^2.1.15",
"docusaurus-pdf": "^1.2.0",
"docusaurus2-dotenv": "^1.4.0",
"env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
"jquery": "^3.6.0",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
"react-chartjs-2": "^4.3.1",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-icons": "^4.4.0",
"react-markdown-editor-lite": "^1.3.2",
"react-paginate": "^8.1.3",
"react-player": "^2.10.1",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"dotenv": "^16.0.2"
}
}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore invalid self-signed ssl certificate in node.js with https.request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888610/ignore-invalid-self-signed-ssl-certificate-in-node-js-with-https-request)