# How to ignore self signed certificate in XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, typescript, https, xmlhttprequest, ssl-certificate

I am working on a project which is written in javascript. I can see that for requesting, XMLHttpRequest object has been created.

It is working fine for "http" requests but fails for "https". Since I am debugging it in the Development environment, I just want to know **how to ignore self-signed certificate in `XmlHttpRequest` objects?**

While searching I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490723/javascript-xmlhttprequest-ignore-invalid-ssl-certificate),

```
httpreq = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0");
httpreq.setOption(2, 13056);
```

But the answer is not working for morden browsers like Microsoft edge, chorme...

I have also found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763811(v=vs.85).aspx), and it clearly says the setOption() can be used for ignoring ssl certificates.

One difference I can see in my code is that I an creating the httpreq using:

```
httpreq = new xmlhttprequest();//This is for chorme and Firefox
```

So is there any way I can ignore self-signed certificates in XmlHttpRequest?

Answer (score 4):

**The Bad News:**

There is no way to accomplish this with [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) ***directly***. This is logical as SSL needs to be secure on the web as any ability to disable it would present a major security risk.

You are also right that `setOption` is not a standard/modern method under XmlHttpRequest.

**The Good(ish) News:**

What you ***can*** do is accomplish this via a trusted/properly configured proxy, with the example below as a Node/Express server configured to allow the insecure SSL connection:

```
$router.get("/", (oRequest, oResponse) => {
    $nonStrictSSLRequest = require('request').defaults({strictSSL: false});
    
    $nonStrictSSLRequest(
        { url: "https://192.168.1.2:8080/api/apiVer" },
        function (err, oAPIResponse, sBody) {
            oResponse.status(200).json(JSON.parse(sBody));
        }
    );
});
```

I had to do this to support [RainMachine's (stupid HTTPS only) self signed certificates](https://support.rainmachine.com/hc/en-us/articles/228022248-Controlling-RainMachine-through-REST-API).

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing on Chromium based browser, you can use flag `--ignore-certificate-errors`. Always pass also `--user-data-dir` to prevent affecting of your main secure profile. Use this only as last resort and only during local development, as this completely ignores all SSL errors. `--ignore-certificate-errors` is undocumented flag, which can be removed from chromium at any time.

**Chromium Linux:**

```
chromium-browser --ignore-certificate-errors --user-data-dir=~/chromium_dev_session
```

**Chrome Windows:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --user-data-dir="c:/chrome_dev_session"
```

[image: Chromium XHR test with --ignore-certificate-errors]