# JavaScript net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: javascript, ssl, postman, ssl-certificate

If I use Postman I have to disable the SSL validation and it works fine. If I don't disable it, it says that there is an error and suggest to disable it. When I copy the Javascript code generated from Postman and run it in on chrome, on the console I receive this error: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID. What can I do? Thank you.

Comment: Try disabling certificate verification in chrome, first link from google: https://kinsta.com/blog/your-connection-is-not-private/

Comment: I think I have done it but not from this link: in this link I don't find where it is

Comment: *"What can I do?"* - it is not clear what you want to achieve. Just make the problem vanish even if it is insecure - disable certificate validation. Make the problem vanish but in a secure way - then you need to find out why the CA is considered invalid and fix the underlying issue. The latter is typically if the CA is not trusted by the browser (like with self-signed certificates) or that the server is not setup properly and an intermediate certificate is missing.

Comment: Even if it is insecure, to try, I want to disable certificate validation. I found this command: "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --user-data-dir="c:/chrome_dev_session" (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685016/how-to-ignore-self-signed-certificate-in-xmlhttprequest)
that should open a chrome window without ssl necessity, and here the error changes in net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE